# Memory leak when dynamically update TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx-2, tableview, javafx-8

I have a lot of memory leak when I dynamically update my table in JavaFX project. I have three methods. start after i press button CreateModel. Then in end of this method I call initTable() and initData() that init columns and put data in table.
When I press CreateModel several times memory usage of my program increase from ~100mb to 250-350mb. When I comment this two methods, and program works without updating table I don't have memory leak.

```
    @FXML
        protected void handleButtonCreateAction(ActionEvent event) throws Throwable {
            processes = Integer.parseInt(textFieldProcesses.getText());
            resources = Integer.parseInt(textFieldResources.getText());

            banker.init(resources, processes, Integer.parseInt(textFieldMaxResourceCount.getText()));
            if(myThread == null) {
                myThread = new MyThread(this, banker);
            } else {
                myThread.stop();
                myThread.finalize();//Bug fix
                myThread = null;
                myThread = new MyThread(this, banker);
            }
            autoModeCheckBox.setSelected(false);
            myThread.setAutoMode(false);
            //TODO: bug when create sleep time from slider is not in Thread


            initColumns();
            initData();
        }

        void initColumns() {
            mainTableView.getColumns().clear();
            mainTableView.getColumns().add(createProcessColumn());
            for (int i = 1; i <= resources; i++) {
                mainTableView.getColumns().add(newResourceColumn(i));
            }
        }

        void initData() {
            tableData = banker.genRows();
            mainTableView.setItems(tableData);

            ObservableList<TableColumn> headerColumnsList = mainTableView.getColumns();
            for(int i = 1; i < headerColumnsList.size(); i++) {
                TableColumn resourceUsageColumn = (TableColumn) headerColumnsList.get(i).getColumns().get(0);
                resourceUsageColumn.setText(String.valueOf(banker.getResourceUsage(i-1)) + "/" + String.valueOf(banker.getResourceCount(i-1)));
            }
        }

        void clearTable() {
            if (tableData != null) {
                tableData.clear();
                //mainTableView.setItems(tableData);
            }
        }

private TableColumn createProcessColumn() {
        TableColumn containerColumn = new TableColumn();//containerColumn

        TableColumn subContainerColumn = new TableColumn();//subContainerColumn

        TableColumn processColumn = new TableColumn("Process");//processColumn
        processColumn.setMinWidth(TABLE_PROCESSES_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        processColumn.setResizable(false);
        processColumn.setSortable(false);

        /*processColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>() {

            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(0).toString());//number in param.getValue().get(number) pointed to row number of data in our List
            }

        });*/

        processColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() { //TODO: If use this type of set CellFactory you can't sort columns

                                         @Override
                                         public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                                             return new TableCell() {

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                                                     super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                                     this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgrey");
                                                     if (!isEmpty()) {
                                                         if (!banker.getWorkingProcesses().contains(this.getIndex()))
                                                             this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:darkgray");//if this process finished his work
                                                         setText(tableData.get(this.getIndex()).get(0).toString()); //getIndex return number of this cell in column
                                                     } else {//TODO: Bug fix
                                                         setText(null);
                                                         setStyle(null);
                                                         setEffect(null);
                                                     }
                                                 }

                                             };
                                         }

                                     });

        subContainerColumn.getColumns().add(processColumn);
        containerColumn.getColumns().add(subContainerColumn);
        return containerColumn;
    }

    private TableColumn newResourceColumn(final int index) {
        TableColumn resourceColumn = new TableColumn("Resource" + String.valueOf(index));//resourceColumn

        TableColumn resourceUsageColumn = new TableColumn("-/-");//TODO: rename

        TableColumn allocationColumn = new TableColumn("Alloc");//allocationColumn
        allocationColumn.setMinWidth(TABLE_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        allocationColumn.setPrefWidth(TABLE_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        allocationColumn.setMaxWidth(TABLE_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        allocationColumn.setResizable(false);
        allocationColumn.setSortable(false);
        allocationColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new TableCell() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            if (!banker.getWorkingProcesses().contains(this.getIndex())) { //if this process finished his work
                                this.setStyle(TABLE_CELL_FINISHED_COLOR);
                                this.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                this.setEffect(null);
                            }
                            else if ((this.getIndex() == banker.getRequest().getProcess()) && (index == banker.getRequest().getResource()+1)) {//if this cell contained in request
                                this.setStyle(TABLE_ALLOC_CELL_SELECTED_COLOR);
                                this.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                                InnerShadow innerShadow = new InnerShadow();
                                innerShadow.setRadius(TABLE_CELL_SHADOW_RADIUS);
                                innerShadow.setColor(Color.gray(0, TABLE_CELL_SHADOW_OPACITY));
                                this.setEffect(innerShadow);
                            }
                            else {//if this cell not contained in request
                                this.setStyle(TABLE_ALLOC_CELL_COLOR);
                                this.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                this.setEffect(null);
                            }
                            setText(tableData.get(this.getIndex()).get(index * 2 - 1).toString()); //getIndex return number of this cell in column
                        } else { //TODO: Bug fix
                            setText(null);
                            setStyle(null);
                            setEffect(null);
                        }
                    }

                };
            }

        });
```

Comment: And what is `MyThread`?

Comment: This program is a Banker algorithm. myThread is Runnable that call Bankers method in other thread.

Comment: After all calculation for current iteration is done, myThread call .clearTable() and .initTable() methods, but after lot of iterations, I no have memory leak. But if I create new model I have it.

Comment: To get help - remove everything which is not relevant to the issue at hand and add everything which is missing so that somebody could copy and paste the application to run it and replicate the issue - [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's your evidence that there's a memory leak? As far as I can tell, your event handler code rebuilds a table from scratch, so obviously it will consume a bunch more memory to allocate all those new objects. How do you know the garbage collector just hasn't determined it needs to run yet?

Comment: This is screenshot of my program http://i.piccy.info/i9/aee13ad62eedd3872037713fc11c07aa/1427323196/79568/888552/Snymok_ekrana_2015_03_26_v_00_38_36.png.

Comment: I tried to create a new table 10x10 several times and that's what I got.
121.5mb -> 156.3mb -> 188.9mb -> 197.9mb -> 211.6mb -> 230.1mb -> 254.8mb. I'm new in Java, this is my second program with GUI in JAVA, so I do not know many things. How to run aggregator garbage?

Comment: The garbage collector will run when it figures out it needs to run... I'm not convinced you have a memory leak. Can you actually get it to run out of memory entirely?

Comment: I delete a lot of code to simplify project. You need use library LU in /libs folder to run project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33655787/Bankir.zip

Comment: I try create 100x100 model many times, after the program was consume 2.18Gb program is not responding. I do not see that garbage collector is work. I try to call         System.gc() , but it not work to.